# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types using DBNull.Value ? Convert

Tags: c#, dbnull

I am trying to read the values out of a database that I am aware is null in the criteria I am looking for right now.
So I had this method of checking for that: `ld.Percentage = reader["DataWin3Data"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(reader["DataWin3Data"]) : double.MinValue;` 
I have used it before where a field can be null and it hasn't had a problem. I am not totally sure what to do in this situation as to how to fix it. I have included my relevant code below. How can change what I am doing currently to not have have this error when there is a null value?

```
ld.Percentage = reader["DataWin3Data"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(reader["DataWin3Data"]) : double.MinValue;
ld.TotalCases = reader["DataWin8Data"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(reader["DataWin8Data"]) : int.MinValue;
ld.TotalPercentage = reader["DataWin7Data"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(reader["DataWin7Data"]) : double.MinValue;
```

Comment: How about `Double.TryParse` instead?  More lines of code perhaps, but safer.

Comment: @DonBoitnott may not be a bad idea would it matter if it is coming out of reader?

Comment: Shouldn't.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363185/parsing-a-decimal-from-a-datareader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
ld.Percentage = reader["DataWin3Data"] == DBNull.Value 
                ? double.MinValue : (double)reader["DataWin3Data"];
```

I've used code like this many times without issue. Are you sure that you're always reading the same field that you're also checking for null?

Also, don't use `Convert` when you're not actually converting. This should be a cast (like in my example).

If that doesn't work, it might be that you're doing something weird with the data. Perhaps some serialization on the way? Try this:

```
ld.Percentage = reader["DataWin3Data"] is DBNull 
                ? double.MinValue : (double)reader["DataWin3Data"];
```

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful I will abstain from using convert and I have figured it out not all the fields that can be null have the check on it there for throwing error.

Comment: I have another question this seems to work when there is null but when  the field is filled it gives me the same error. Is there not a way to do that using the above?

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos Are you *sure* that's the line where the error occurs? Check the name of the columns. Or rather, write it all as a method so that you don't rely on typo-less code :D